# magento2 custom payment with external redirect

Tags: redirect, paypal, payment, magento2, gateway

Has anybody made this? I am trying to make a custom payment with external redirect and I have read everything and still can't make it work. Has anybody made a custom payment which requires an external redirection to the bank's page? I have read the paypal workflow and other stuff but if somebody has actually made it (not in theory) , then would be glad to get their help...:)

Answer (score 0):

In your payment model class you have to specify **getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()**

```
protected $_canUseCheckout= true;

public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
    return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('magento4u/payment/redirect', ['_secure' => true]);
}
```